# How can you host Django REST API on a home server (possibly on an Android phone)?

Tags: android, linux, django, rest, server

I would like to go to a job interview and show some portfolio with REST API that doesn't cost money to maintain, I don't want to use free trials on AWS and such either. I want something like PAW server that does Python code, also I have no idea about what ports to open, how to open them and how to keep them secure

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following free Django Hosting Platforms:

- [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)
- [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/)

There might be more available out there on the internet but these are one of the best when it comes to Free Django Hosting for testing/personal projects.

Comment: and this includes building a private REST API with Secret API keys that only I know and hands http responses lets say for an android app?

Comment: I think this another problem statement. For authentication that you can use Django REST Framework which has become a standard these days.

Comment: found that tunneling is closer to what i was asking, couldnt find any way to do tunneling through a Smartphone tho :'(